# Code snippet in Chrome to repeatedly fetch URL doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api

I can use this code in the Chrome console to make a post request to a URL on my `localhost`:

```
fetch("http://localhost:50014/api/myapi/", {"credentials":"omit","headers":{"accept":"*/*","accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8","cache-control":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json","pragma":"no-cache","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-site":"cross-site","x-api-key":"abc123"},"referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":"{\"nodeIds\":[\"ABC123\"]}","method":"POST","mode":"cors"});
```

I'm using this code as a Chrome 'Snippet' in the developer tools, to try to repeatedly make a post request, for some test purposes where I'm trying to identify an error:

```
while(1==1) {
fetch("http://localhost:50014/api/myapi/", {"credentials":"omit","headers":{"accept":"*/*","accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8","cache-control":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json","pragma":"no-cache","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-site":"cross-site","x-api-key":"abc123"},"referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":"{\"nodeIds\":[\"ABC123\"]}","method":"POST","mode":"cors"});
setTimeout(() => {  console.log("waiting"); }, 1000);
}
```

But I never see the POST request take effect, and there's nothing in the console. Why?

**Update**

Thanks @Jaromanda X. I update to this but it's still not running. Why?

```
while(1==1){
  callApi();
  sleep(5000);
}

function callApi() {
    fetch("http://localhost:50014/api/myapi/", {"credentials":"omit","headers":{"accept":"*/*","accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8","cache-control":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json","pragma":"no-cache","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-site":"cross-site","x-api-key":"abc123"},"referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":"{\"nodeIds\":[\"ABC123\"]}","method":"POST","mode":"cors"});
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
   var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

   while (currentTime + milliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
   }
}
```

Comment: your while loop sends thousands of requests in a tight loop - there's no waiting, because that's not how setTimeout works - eventually your browser should warn you that there's javascript that is making the page unresponsive - if not - use a modern browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make request after a period of time repeatedly, you can use setInterval like below:

```
setInterval(()=>{

fetch("http://localhost:50014/api/myapi/", {"credentials":"omit","headers":{"accept":"*/*","accept-language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8","cache-control":"no-cache","content-type":"application/json","pragma":"no-cache","sec-fetch-mode":"cors","sec-fetch-site":"cross-site","x-api-key":"abc123"},"referrerPolicy":"no-referrer","body":"{\"nodeIds\":[\"ABC123\"]}","method":"POST","mode":"cors"});

},5000)
```